# How to export google docs revision with v3 drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

How can I export specific version of Google document?

I want to create an exact slice copy of user's gdrive.

The idea is

1. Get list of head revisions for all files in drive
2. Download or export every file with exact revision

But for google docs files I can't find an `head revision` field in `/files/list/`:

```
 {
   "id": "1Vsg1U58vXPCGqL2KFAT-cY9ckAIwWxQQ0-49HOPtHzI",
   "name": "Spreadsheet-test-file-1",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "version": "844"
  },
```

and when I list all revisions for this file, I get this:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#revisionList",
 "revisions": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#revision",
   "id": "1",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "modifiedTime": "2017-07-04T07:21:24.849Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#revision",
   "id": "2",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "modifiedTime": "2017-07-04T07:21:24.852Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

But when I try to download this revision, I get an error `Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.`

I know that API docs says that Google docs can't be downloaded with revisions. But if so, I don't understand how to get the exact slice of the drive?

By the way, I am using the Go library for drive api.

Comment: I did try this and I'm also experiencing the same error. If not that, I'm getting "The requested conversion is not supported". Haven't tried this yet but try the workaround where you open (not download directly) the contents of the revision by using [Revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get) and save that as a new file. Since it's a new file, go ahead and download it.

Comment: Although I think that this is a temporal workaround, how about this method? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034778/google-drive-api-v3-get-the-content-of-a-revision/44036350#44036350

Comment: @Tanaike even if it works, I need to somehow get list of all revisions for this docs, but I can's just list all files, and get revisions for them. Instead, I have to make separate requests for each google document to get it's revisions.
So this method make no sense since I want to make a complete slice of Drive at current time.

Comment: @kudinovdenis I apologize for not being helpful.